# django syncdb does not appear to run my custom hook

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

I have some existing SQL statements that I'd like to use as a custom hook after the CREATE TABLE command, in [myapp]/sql/[model-name].sql.

My app is in INSTALLED_APPS. I see  listed if I run `./manage.py sql`.

My custom hook is found; I see the SQL statements output if I run any of the following:

`./manage.py sqlall <myapp>`
`./manage.py sqlcustom <myapp>`
`./manage.py sql <myapp>`

I'm using postgres 9.x on my mac.

If I `psql` to that same database (with no user) and copy them from the .sql file and paste them into the psql command input, they all work... so I believe they're valid SQL understood by postgres.  These are all pretty simple INSERT statements (fixtures addressed below).

However, if I run `./manage.py syncdb` those statements are either not run, or they are ignored or silent errors happen; all I know is that the new rows do not appear in the database. I am tailing the postgres log file and nothing is logged when I run syncdb, so I don't know if it's not finding my .sql file, or parsing it and finding some error before it gets to the database.

I have created a .json file, for fixtures, with the equivalent of those statements, and `./manage.py loaddata <path-to-json-file>` works correctly: my site now shows those values in the database.  This makes me believe that my settings file is correct and the database I'm writing to inside postgres is set correctly, and I have write permissions when I run `./manage.py`.

I saw in some other post that the django documentation is wrong and I should put the custom hook in the 'models' directory, but I don't know if that's right; if `sqlall` and `sqlcustom` find my hook, shouldn't `syncdb` find it?  Also I don't (yet) have a models directory and may not need it.

For various reasons I'd rather not use JSON format, but if I have to I will... however I've invested so much time in the .sql format I really want to know what's going on (and I've seen enough existing related questions that this might help others).

Comment: I confirm, if your models package is a subdirectory then yes, the sql directory has to be inside models.

There is an accepted ticket asking to change the documentation about it https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18954

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.  I switched to the models-directory format (and learned a bunch in the process!). Then I put the .sql file inside an sql directory inside models.  The title of the .sql file is 'tile.sql' which matches a 'tile.py' inside models, but it's still not being called.  Is there something more do you know?

Comment: I believe I found it, although it's based on behaviors not any real research.  I simply changed 'tile' to 'tilexx' everywhere and it worked. [This post](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6685) indicates that if there is some sort of name conflict the custom SQL won't be executed... and 'tile' is a pretty common thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found it, although it's based on behaviors not any real research. I simply changed 'tile' to 'tilexx' everywhere and it worked. [This django-project post](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6685) indicates that if there is some sort of python class name conflict the custom SQL won't be executed... and 'tile' is a pretty common thing.

So the answer is to change the name of my class to something a bit more unique.

Comment: Marking my answer as answered, since it did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for an answer to a similar problem, trying to initialize an sqlite database with data I dumped from a Flask application I'm porting to Django. Like the OP, all of the following did the right thing:

```
./manage.py sqlall <myapp> ./manage.py sqlcustom <myapp> ./manage.py sql <myapp>
```

However, the insert statements in myapp/sql/myapp.sql were not being run. A careful reading of the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/initial-data/) revealed this clue:

> Django provides a hook for passing the database arbitrary SQL that’s **executed just after the CREATE TABLE statements** when you run syncdb.

(emphasis added)

The issue is that I had already registered my models and run syncdb, so the table in question already existed in the database, although it held no data yet. I deduce that because of this, the `CREATE TABLE` statement was not being run on subsequent executions of syncdb, and therefore, my custom sql could not be run after that statement. The solution was to `DROP table table_name` and then run syncdb again, at which point my custom sql was run.